# How can I cut the word after certain symbols?

Tags: javascript

I have such a structure `"\"item:Test:3:Facebook\""` and I need somehow fetch the word Facebook.

The words can be dynamic. So I need to get word which is after third : and before `\`

I tried var `arr = str.split(":").map(item => item.trim())` but it doesn't do what I need. How can I cut a word that will be after third `:` ?

Comment: Your code is already working? Just get the 4th item of the array. `arr = str.split(":").map(item => item.trim())[3]`.

Answer (score 3):

A litte extra code to remove the last `"` aswell.

```js
var str = "\":Test:3:Facebook\"";
var arr = str.split(":").map(item => item.trim());
var thirdItem = arr[3].replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, "");
console.log(thirdItem);
```

Comment: yeah but this remove symbols between words, as & for example Oil & Gas

Answer (score 2):

If the amount of colons (`:`) doesn't vary you can simply use an index on the resulting array like this:

```
var foo = str.split(":")[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

The word after the 3rd `:` will be the fourth word returned, so it will be at index `3` in the array returned by split() (arrays being zero-indexed, of course).  You might also want to get rid of the trailing quote mark.
Demo:

```js
str = "\"item:Test:3:Facebook\"";
var word = str.split(":")[3].replace("\"", "");
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Don't the triple quotation marks break the replace function (`"\""`)? Shouldn't it therefore be `.replace('\"', "")`

Comment: @Sv443 what triple quotation marks are you referring to please? P.S. you can run my code above for yourself by clicking the button, and see that it works.

Comment: I'm referring to the ones in the replace function. Also I know that it works but I don't understand why

Comment: @Sv443 because the backslash is an escape character. Just like in the original `str` variable.

Comment: @Sv443 [obligatory documentation link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation)

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, plus remove all symbols

```
var foo = str.split(":")[3].replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "")
```

Comment: this removes symbols between words, for example if I will have Oil & Gas, it will remove & but I need it

Comment: how about `str.split(":")[3].replace(/[^a-zA-Z& ]/g, "");`   and you could add any other symbol that you need there.